# Почему я получаю ошибку?

Tags: php, composer

по адресу `https://site.net/translate/server.php`

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "YourNamespace\AudioStream" not found in /sites/site.net/translate/server.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /sites/criptopays.net/translate/server.php on line 16
```

server.php

```
    <?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServerInterface;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use AudioStream;

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new AudioStream()
        )
    ),
    8080
);

$server->run();
```

AudioStream.php

```
    <?php
namespace YourNamespace; // Замените на ваше пространство имен
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class AudioStream implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($client !== $from) {
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

Как исправить данную ошибку? Файлы server.php и AudioStream.php находятся в одной директории

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуй в сервер импортировать без namespace в виде `use AudioStream`. Так как в одном пространстве имен лежат файлы, то импортировать нужно без указания оного.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "AudioStream" not found in /sites/criptopays.net/translate/server.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /sites/criptopays.net/translate/server.php on line 14

Comment: там у вас в коде написано ``// Замените на ваше пространство имен``

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете `namespace YourNamespace` в двух разных файлах.

Каждый файл должен иметь свое пространсво имен, измените название и попробуйте.
Я думаю, что причина в этом.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "AudioStream" not found in /sites/site.net/translate/server.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /sites/criptopays.net/translate/server.php on line 14

Comment: @eypro-corp покажи полный код

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: "Каждый файл должен иметь свое пространсво имен" -- Вы уверены? Потому что звучит так, как-будто два и больше файлов не могут быть в одном пространстве имен и у каждого файла оно должно быть уникальным, что собственно, не есть таковым.